# Add js file to meteor project

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a very simple question.
I'm doing the simple-todos tutorial of meteor.

I want t add a utils.js file.

For now it only has :

```
function foo () {
    return "text";
}
```

I've placed the file under myapp/client

And I'm trying to reach it from simple-todos.js,
But I keep getting an error, saying foo is not defined.

How can I add a utils.js file that will be accessible by simple-todos.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836390/how-can-i-access-constants-in-the-lib-constants-js-file-in-meteor/26838580#26838580. To solve your issue, simply write `foo = function() {/*...*/};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor applies scoping of variables to each file, including functions. You just need to globally define it. This means don't use the `var` keyword when you want to access it from other files:

Instead of

```
function foo () {
    return "text";
}

//Which is similar to

var foo = function () {
    return "text";
}
```

Use:

```
foo = function () {
    return "text";
}
```