# meteor no such function error in production only

Tags: meteor

when I start meteor like this:

```
meteor --production
```

I get a blank page where my app should be and the following error shows up in my browser console:

```
No such function: navClassName
```

However if I start meteor normally like this:

```
meteor
```

My app runs without problem.

What could be the problem? Do meteor template helpers need to be loaded differently during production?

Relevant files:
client/navigation/navigation.html:

```
<template name="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="{{navClassName 'home'}}">
            <a href="{{pathFor 'home'}}">home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="{{navClassName 'blog'}}">
            <a href="{{pathFor 'blog'}}">Blog</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

client/navigation/navigation.js:

```
Template.navigation.helpers({
  'navClassName': function (route) {
    if (Router.current()) {
      return Router.current().route.options.navbarSelected.search(route) != -1 ? "active" : "";
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move *navigation.js* to the *client/lib* directory, or at least the `Template.navigation.helpers` part and fix/remove any other JavaScript that is causing errors.

I wish I could elaborate more, but this issue seems to be related to the file load order. Files in the *lib* directory are loaded first and moving the helpers there solved the problem for me.

A typical file structure can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp). See the comments in the **Example File Structure** to learn about some of the special behaviors.

While this may work for you, finer control over dependencies can most easily be achieved through [packages](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs), as explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26838580/4183217) from SO. This is specially necessary for code that should be available to both client and server.