# leanest way for city & country selection and exact address selection

Tags: json, http, methods, meteor, get

What is the most light weight method to allow users to select their city and country? I am aiming to make it so that the user begins to type their city and a limited number of suggestion pop up.

I have used typeahead.js and populated a variable with 247 countries on the client. But offering the entire worlds city list as well to the user is inefficient.

I have downloaded a json file that contains all the countries and their respective cities from https://github.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/blob/master/countriesToCities.json

Considering this file to be 2MB in size, it is not significant for the functionality of my app so I dont want the client to download it all.

There is a good explanation on [Importing a JSON file in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374066/importing-a-json-file-in-meteor) on how to call the file from the server.

1) Where do I place the .json file to retrieve the file from the server via a http call? There is a lib in root directory but it can also be placed in server>lib>

Comment: Put *.json to `public` folder to be able to retrieve it using HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leanest way would be use the native Meteor [autocomplete package](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/autocomplete) and populate a collection with the cities from the JSON file via [mongoimport --type json](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

Check out the demos at http://autocomplete.meteor.com.

Meteor's DDP protocol is more efficient and simpler than the old-school REST style of data transfer. With the autocomplete package, you won't even need to write any code actually.

Comment: I have realised when the user is inserting their publication location, it will be their business address. I guess I will have to use some API. So I might as well use the API for the city and country location as well. I will edit my question

Comment: @CodeCandy: Google's [Places autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) is very easy to use.